# Check two columns for two different conditions and return true when both are satisfied

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Q: Only dealers with "Excellent" estimate qualities received both shipping rebate and sales volume bonus?
Basically, I need to find if any dealer has an "Excellent" value in L column and a "TRUE" value in O column.
Refer the attached photo for your understanding.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as given below

[image]

Or if you are looking for something else,provide more details

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(AND(B1 = "Excellent", C1 = TRUE), "PASS", "FAIL")
```